# Retrieving full name from AD in an autorun application

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am trying retrieve the full name of the user, that is currently logged in.

It usually works fine with this small snippet, I found:

```
[Export(typeof(IAdManager))]
public class AdManager : IAdManager
{
    public string GetFullName()
    {
        try
        {
            DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.UserDomainName + "/" + Environment.UserName);
            return de.Properties["fullName"].Value.ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it stops working, when I am trying to start the application on Windows start. The result is an empty (or null?) string.

I've put a shortcut in here:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Any ideas, why exactly it's not working? Is it because that Location actually loads up the applications before the user logs in?

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the `FullName` directly from AD.

```
public static string GetFullName()
{
   using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yourdomain.com"))
   {
      string username = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
      using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, username))
      {
         if (user != null)
         {
            return user.DisplayName;
         }
      }
   }
   return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I appreciate your help :) I already solved my problem using UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName, but I hope your answer helps someone´else anyways.